# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, literals

I'm writing a program that reads the letters in one txt file and then the words in another and puts them back together. In the pos.txt you have:  1231 and in the new file.txt you have the cat said cat. I'm getting the error about invalid literal for int. Not sure why when I have converted the string to int before printing on screen?

```
for position in WordPositionsList:
    OriginalSentence = OriginalSentence  + " " + SentenceWordsList[int(position) - 1]
    # need to subtract 1 because WordPositions list starts at zero and original positions were stored starting at one
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Could you post only the relevant code and possibly a traceback please?

Comment: Evidently, at least one of your files or variables doesn't contain what you expect it to. Do some debugging to discover where your program and your expectations diverge. You only use `int` once in this code, so if I were you, I'd start there: Does `position ` contain what you think it does?

Comment: Try printing `position` before you convert it to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

By using `WordPositionsList = WordPositions.split(" ")` , you are assuming that the pos.txt file has spaces between each position character.

You can fix your issue by either making sure your characters do have spaces, or making a list of each character in the line assuming no spaces, i.e.

```
WordPositionsList = [char for char in WordPositions]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `WordPositionsList` is a `list` of words then your `position` variable in your `for` loop is going to store the current word in the iteration and not an `int`.